# Primary Key violation after checking for existence of row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Question:  What things could cause the following problem?

We have a stored proc that updates or inserts a price record into a table.  Very straight forward.  However, at intermittent times we get a primary key violation trying to insert a row that already exists.  As you see, we are checking for the existence of a record and then updating or inserting as appropriate.

This happens very rarely but the last time it happened we had 18 occurrences in a 3 minute window.  We updated a lot more rows than 18 so it is not every time. This SP is called quite often.  We check and there was no index maintenance going on at the time.  The application that calls this SP just loops through a queue to update/insert these prices and there is only one instance of the application running.

This is running on an 2016 Availability Group with 3 servers.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mw_UpdatePrice] @CustTypeID INT
    ,@ID INT
    ,@Price MONEY
    ,@OldPrice MONEY
    ,@ExpirationDate DATETIME
    ,@PriceStatusID INT
    ,@PriceStatusDesc VARCHAR(80)
    ,@FreeFreightShipviaServiceLevelID INT = NULL
    ,@FreeFreightShipViaServiceLevelDescription VARCHAR(150) = NULL
    ,@FreeFreightShipViaServiceLevelRank INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.Price
            WHERE ID = @ID
                AND CustTypeID = @CustTypeID
            )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Price
        SET Price = @Price
            ,OldPrice = @OldPrice
            ,ExpirationDate = @ExpirationDate
            ,PriceStatusID = @PriceStatusID
            ,PriceStatusDescription = @PriceStatusDesc
            ,ServiceLevelName = @FreeFreightShipViaServiceLevelDescription
            ,ServiceLevelId = @FreeFreightShipviaServiceLevelID
            ,ServiceLevelRank = @FreeFreightShipViaServiceLevelRank
        WHERE ID = @ID
            AND CustTypeID = @CustTypeID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT dbo.Price (
            ID
            ,CustTypeID
            ,Price
            ,OldPrice
            ,ExpirationDate
            ,PriceStatusID
            ,PriceStatusDescription
            ,ServiceLevelName
            ,ServiceLevelID
            ,ServiceLevelRank
            )
        VALUES (
            @ID
            ,@CustTypeID
            ,@Price
            ,@OldPrice
            ,@ExpirationDate
            ,@PriceStatusID
            ,@PriceStatusDesc
            ,@FreeFreightShipViaServiceLevelDescription
            ,@FreeFreightShipviaServiceLevelID
            ,@FreeFreightShipViaServiceLevelRank
            )
    END
END
```

Comment: What is your Primary Key?  Is it a composite key of `ID` and `CustTypeID`? Could you edit the Table's DDL into your post? If it's not a composite key, there's your problem; you're checking if an entry for a specific `ID` and `CustTypeID`, thus if the `ID` exists but for a different `CustTypeID`, you'll get a violation.

Comment: First of all you have to do that kind of work in a transaction. Second: this type of problem is the best candidate for the MERGE statement. Check this here https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: @Larnu That is the PK.  I double checked.

Comment: @SteveB What is? Just `ID`?

Comment: @MihailShishkov This has been in place for a while so I don't know why it uses the structure it does.  I do remember there were some issues with MERGE in weird situations so that may be why.  I bet the transaction may solve the problem.  Sad I didn't think of that.

Comment: This database is 99% Reads.  This is one of two procs that do updates and is the only thing that updates this table.  I am still a little confused as to why it would be happening.

Comment: @Larnu  The key is both fields.

Comment: @SteveB if you write  MERGE the correct way for your situation, this is the best thing you can do. And hey that's called refactoring, leaving the code in a better state that it was before :)

Comment: @MihailShishkov  Agreed!  I still wish I could understand why it is happening and only some of the time.

Comment: @SteveB because you have something that is trying to insert two records with the same ID very very fast. Remember code takes time to execute so if two threads/clients call your procedure in the "exact" same time you have two "instances" of the procedure executing in parallel. So the first IF EXISTS starts executing and the second IF EXISTS start executing. Both of them return 0 because there is actually no such ID but one of the procedures will be first to make the actual insert leaving the other to fail. That's called race condition. Hope this makes sense. Cheers

Comment: @MihailShishkov I get that but this application updates/inserts 1 row at a time.  There isn't a race as far as I can tell.  I was hoping there was something else that could be causing it.  The table gets read from constantly but this is the only application writing to it.  Thanks for the idea about the transaction/MERGE.

Answer (score 1):

As comments have mentioned, this stored procedure is not safe to call concurrently - it has race conditions for both insert and update scenarios. This can be fixed only by ensuring that each call to the stored procedure is contained in a separate transaction (add begin/end tran inside the SP, or initiate transaction from the application code), and applying `HOLDLOCK` to the SELECT and INSERT statements:

```
SELECT 1
FROM dbo.Price WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
WHERE ID = @ID
    AND CustTypeID = @CustTypeID
```

...

```
INSERT dbo.Price WITH (HOLDLOCK)
...
```

Even if this gets refactored to a `MERGE` statement, `HOLDLOCK` will still be necessary to prevent the issue. Example [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).

`HOLDLOCK` locks the entire table and will reduce the concurrent throughput of this SP.

Aside from the concurrency problem, another possible cause of PRIMARY KEY violation could occur if ANSI_NULLS is on, potentially allowing for an application logic error where the SP is being called with NULL values for @CustTypeID or @ID, causing the application to behave in a way that wasn't intended. For example, calling with @CustTypeID = NULL and @ID = 1 would always result in an INSERT, which might not be the intended behavior.

**Edit:**

Added `UPDLOCK` as per @DavidBrowne

Comment: HOLDLOCK is not enough with SELECT.  Both sessions will acquire a S Range lock, and then deadlock on INSERT.  You would need (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK) here.  With MERGE the UPDLOCK is not needed as MERGE reads with U locks, just like UPDATE.  But SELECT will read with S locks by default

Comment: @DanLing  My only problem is that this SP isn't called concurrently as far as we can see.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is maybe the caller of the SP is sending a null value for one of the primary key columns. You could add a validation to this SP to throw an error if Id or CustTypeID is null.

Comment: @DanLing Luckily in our error logging we have the actual data and it isn't null.